# How to set $\alpha,\beta$ such that $logit^{-1}(\alpha X_1+\beta X_2)$ has a mean of 0.4 with $X_1 \sim Bern(p)$ and $X_2\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability, variance, optimization

I am working in `R`, and am trying to generate values of

$$
logit^{-1}(\alpha X_1+\beta X_2)
$$

with $\alpha,\beta$ such that $logit^{-1}(\alpha X_1+\beta X_2)$ has a mean of 0.4 with as small a variance as possible. I have that $X_1 \sim Bern(0.5)$ and that $X_2\sim N(0.5,0.01)$.

My code is:

```
X1 <- rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.5) 
X2 <- rnorm(100, mean=0.5, sd=0.1)    
logit.inverse <- function(x) exp(x)/(1+exp(x))
alpha <- -5
beta  <- 5
mean(logit.inverse(alpha*X1+beta*X2))
var(logit.inverse(alpha*X1+beta*X2))
```

The results above are $0.5175315$ for the mean, and $0.1776111$ for the variance.

I am wondering if there is an optimization technique to make it so that the mean is $0.4$ or $0.3$ with as small variance as possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next best thing to a simple formula for an expectation of a random variable is a zillion random samples for that random variable.  Below is some *R* code to estimate the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that have expectation (approximately) 0.4 and (approximate) minimum variance.

First a large number of random samples are taken and a contour plot of the expectations associated with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to get a lay of the land:

```
# Generate a large random sample
  nsim <- 10000
  x1 <- rbinom(nsim, size = 1, prob = 0.5) 
  x2 <- rnorm(nsim, mean=0.5, sd=0.1)    

# Function to estimate mean and variance of 
#  1 - 1/(1+exp(alpha*X1 + beta*X2))
  logit.inverse <- function(a, b) {
    data.frame(mean = mean(1 - 1/(exp(a*x1 + b*x2))),
      var = var(1 - 1/(exp(a*x1 + b*x2))))
  }

# Create a grid of estimated expectations 
  xmin <- -2
  xmax <- 2
  ymin <- -1
  ymax <- 3
  n <- 100 # Number of grid cells in each direction
  z <- matrix(rep(NA,(n+1)^2), nrow=n+1)
  for (i in 1:(n+1)) {
      a <- xmin + (xmax-xmin)*(i-1)/n
      for (j in 0:n) {
          b <- ymin + (ymax-ymin)*(j-1)/n
          z[i,j] <- logit.inverse(a,b)$mean
      }                                                
  }

# Create a contour plot to see what's what
  par(ask=TRUE)
  contour(xmin + (xmax-xmin)*c(0:n)/n, ymin + (ymax-ymin)*c(0:n)/n, z,
    levels = c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7), xlab="alpha", ylab="beta",
    labcex=1, las=1, main="E(1-1/(1+exp(alpha*X1+beta*X2)))")

# Get contour line for the expectation = 0.4
  k <- contourLines(xmin + (xmax-xmin)*c(0:n)/n, ymin + (ymax-ymin)*c(0:n)/n, z,
    levels = 0.4)[[1]]

# Determine alpha and beta associated with the minimum variance
  v <- rep(NA,length(k$x))
  for (i in 1:length(k$x)) {
      v[i] <- logit.inverse(k$x[i],k$y[i])$var 
  }

# Add in the "optimal" point
  points(k$x[v==min(v)], k$y[v==min(v)], pch=16, col="red", cex=2)
```

[image: Contour plot of expectations]

```
# Summarize results
  cat("alpha =", k$x[v==min(v)],"\n")
  cat("beta =", k$y[v==min(v)],"\n")
  cat("Minimum variance =", min(v),"\n")
```

> alpha = 0.04
>   beta = 0.995488
>   Minimum variance = 0.00372371